# Sharepoint 2010 overwriting file upload with Client Object Model does'nt work

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am trying to upload a file to the  document library using Client Object Model

```
        using MO_NET = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;

        try
        {
            using (MO_NET.ClientContext ctx = new MO_NET.ClientContext("http://server1-sp2010/sitios/LbkPruebasCurso/"))
            {
                MO_NET.List lBibliotecaDocumentos = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documentos compartidos");

                MO_NET.FileCreationInformation fciArchivo = new MO_NET.FileCreationInformation();
                fciArchivo.Content = File.ReadAllBytes(@"..\..\Archivos\RegionInfo.csv");

               //se define el nombre del documento en la biblioteca
                fciArchivo.Overwrite = true;
                fciArchivo.Url = "RegionInfo.csv";

                MO_NET.File fToUpload = lBibliotecaDocumentos.RootFolder.Files.Add(fciArchivo);
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
```

this code works but it seems to me that the

```
  "fciArchivo.Overwrite = true"
```

doesn't work. when i try to upload another file with the same name  i get an exception.
if i delete the file first teh code works

Can i solve that without deleting previously the file in the library

Thanks a lot

Comment: Maybe file is checked out to someone else when you try to overwrite it?

Comment: No it is a development environment and the file is not checked out

Comment: What exception are you getting?

Comment: Message = "Error al ejecutar eventos." google translation  : "Error executing events" Source"Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime" the stack Trace :    en Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ProcessResponseStream(Stream responseStream)
   en Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ProcessResponse()
   en Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.ExecuteQuery()
   en CSOMDemos.Program.CargarArchivo() en c:\Miguel\proyectosSP\07 SPLiberbankAPIDemos\CSOMDemos\Program.cs:línea 231